# Typescript parse json numeric object

Tags: angular, typescript, type-conversion

I'm trying to parse the following json object in typescript. For alphabets its fine but for numbers its showing compile time error.

```
{
"36": [{
    "requestId": 64992,
    "requestNumber": "PQ-17-0068112",
    "requestDate": "16-Apr-2017",
    "requestTypeId": 12,

}]
```

}

```
this._requestService.getDetails( res.requestId)
                                .subscribe(
                                    response => 
                                    {
                                        let r:any = response;
                                        //This line showing error while for alphabets its fine, for numeric its saying ',' expected
                                        console.log(response.36);
                                    }

                                );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use dot syntax with key which is number is js. Try

```
response['36']
```

Comment: That's what I want. Thanks alot